# Discrete analog of CDF: "cumulative mass function"?

Tags: density-function, terminology, discrete-data, cumulative-distribution-function

We call the integral of a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (PDF) a [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF).

But what's the cumulative sum of a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) (PMF) called? I've never heard the term "cumulative mass function" before, and [the Wikipedia page for it redirects to the CDF page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_mass_function), so I'm confused what the proper terminology is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The proper terminology is *Cumulative Distribution Function*, (CDF).  The CDF is defined as
$$F_X(x) = \mathrm{P}\{X \leq x\}.$$
With this definition, the nature of the random variable $X$ is irrelevant: continuous, discrete, or hybrids all have the same definition.
As you note, for a discrete random variable the CDF has a very different appearance than for a continuous random variable.  In the first case, it is a step function; in the second it is a continuous function.

Comment: Just to supplement the answer: if you're looking for the CDF analog of the PMF of a **sample** rather than of a *population*, then the term you're looking for is [*empirical distribution function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function).

Answer (score 0):

I think "cumulative mass function" is correct, but it hasn't been widely adopted just yet. It makes sense to me as a more specific cumulative distribution function, a sibling to probability mass functions, similar to how cumulative density functions relate to probability density functions.